# Find all Joomla 1.5 installs in a cPanel server

Tags: joomla, grep, joomla1.5, cpanel

I am looking for a "find" or "grep" command (I think) that I can run in my cPanel server, in order to find all installs of Joomla 1.5 (1.5.x).

I suppose it needs to cycle through all /home/*/public_html and find a certain Joomla 1.5 signature.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell a Joomla 1.5 install by the following text in the /libraries/joomla/version.php file:

```
Copyright (C) 2005 - 2010 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
```

so your command might look like this or similar:

```
grep -r --include=*version.php "Copyright (C) 2005 - 2010 Open Source Matters" /home/
```